# Why wasn't the truck that hit Captain Windmark teleported with him?

Tags: fringe

In the last episode of *Fringe*, when Captain Windmark tried to grab the boy (the anomaly XB-6783746), Peter Bishop also tried to grab Captain Windmark. The second Peter Bishop touched Captain Windmark, he, Windmark, and the boy were all transported together by Captain Windmark because of his ability to move fast in time.

Why didn't the truck that hit Captain Windmark (the truck was touching Windmark, just like Peter's hands) transported with Windmark? Why was only Windmark transported?

Comment: Did Windmark actually teleport, or was he killed before he could complete the teleportation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't know much about the mechanic of the teleportation ability of the Observer. Everything is defined by what we saw on screen. We know that someone else could be transported along with the observer if he touch him, but we don't know the limit of this phenomenon.

For instance, Observers don't bring a part of the floor each time they teleport.

Something prevented the truck from being transported along with Windmark, it may be speed, mass or anything. He might even go with the truck's bumper, but it doesn't matter. The mechanic of the teleportation ability of the Observer it plot driven an will bend to fit the plot.

Comment: right, i see the point now.

Comment: my impression of that "teleporting" is that they are moving themselves through some kind of extra-dimensional space where they can cross large distances quickly, not "teleporting" themselves from point to point. That's why they have to walk to do it. Windmark started to walk into this subspace and the truck squashed him before he had time to move out of the way.

Answer (score 3):

> He meets the team as they attempt to implement their plan to send Michael to 2167. He engages in a fight with the team and is about to take the boy when Olivia makes use of the remaining Cortexiphan in her system. Windmark turns to face her and witnesses the power in the entire city landscape behind her shut off. A truck is flung at Windmark, sandwiching him in between two vehicles. **He attempts to teleport but just misses his opportunity, instantly dying.**

http://fringe.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Windmark

Comment: but he does teleport. even tho he dies, so i don't think if this answers my question.

Comment: He may have started his teleportation procedure, but he never gets a chance to finish it. He gets squashed by the truck.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the spoiler tags, since this answer is meaningless otherwise (and anyone clicking on this question has already been spoiled anyway).